# CODEIGNITOR 4 VIEWS : ErrorException Undefined variable $title_meta

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

When I place the view addproperty.php in codeignitor default views folder error does not happen and title is displayed properly but when I move it to `ThirdParty\Auth\Views\addproperty.php` error happens.

Logs of error :

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $title_meta
APPPATH\ThirdParty\Auth\Views\addproperty.php at line 7

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   
<head>
    <?= $title_meta ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    <?= $this->include('partials/head-css') ?>
</head>
 
<?= $this->include('partials/body') ?>
```

My home.php controller :

```
public function add_property(){
    $data = [
       'title_meta' => view('partials/title-meta', ['title' => 'Properties']),
       'page_title' => view('partials/page-title', ['title' => 'Add_property', 'li_1' => 
       'Properties', 'li_2' => 'Add Property'])
    ];
    return view('addproperty', $data);
}
```

I am trying to create a title for this page through controller. Anyone has experience about this?

Comment: Views do not belong in the Third Party folder unless you update the reference in App/Config/Paths.php. That is the problem right there - keep it in the default location as that already works or update the View path reference.

Comment: Thank you for response. I am learning CI4, i will appreciate your help. I am using Auth library which is in Thirdparty folder.  Views in this location have sessions; when am logged in views are accessible. When logged out or session expires, views are terminated, it works well but some variables on views pages like $meta_title throw error as undefined variables.

When i move the views to default folder, all works fine but session stops working. Give me directons, thanks. 

The reference in App/Config/Paths.php doesnt contain anything about views default directory on my side.